# How does quantile regression behave when having more variables than observations?

Tags: regression, quantile-regression, high-dimensional

When having a dataset with a larger number of variables than observations, it is not possible to build a linear regression model, because such a model would have an infinite number of possible solution for the variable parameters, and so, tha variance of the solution is infinite. My question is: does quantile regression suffer of the same problem? And if so, can you provide some mathematical explanation for such behaviour?